# How to setup cron job in cpanel? if connection is not secure?

Tags: cron, cpanel

I am trying to setup cron job with following url :

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 https://myexample.com/check/test > /dev/null
```

but this is not working.

When i am trying to execute this url on web  https://myexample.com/check/test

i see message *Your connection is not private*

Answer (score 0):

You will need a SSL certificate to get rid of that security warning. You could use one generated by letsencrypt (which is free). An alternative way would be to get a SSL certificate through startssl.com (also free). If you just need your cron to run you could use it like this:

```
/usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate -O - -q -t 1 https://myexample.com/check/test > /dev/null
```

Accessing the same link via a web browser, without having a valid SSL certificate will result in a security warning. If you do not want to buy or use a real SSL certificate then you could just use Firefox web browser an add an exception for that website/certificate.